# Error in Python IDLE and shell while Proxifier is on

Tags: python, shell

I have recently installed Python 2.7.6 in windows 7. When I tried to open the IDLE, it gave fatal errors.

There are two error message popping up subsequently showing error messages:

1. > "IDLE Subprocess Error"
   >
   > "Socket Error:No connection could be made because the target machine
   >   actively refused it"
2. > "Subprocess Startup Error"
   >
   > "IDLE's subprocess didn't make connection. Either IDLE can't start a
   >   subprocess or personal firewall software is blocking the connection."

then nothing happens.

I figured out that this error occurs only when Proxifier is on. No issue with firewall. I exited Proxifier and the python Shell was working fine. Then I tried to open Proxifier after opening shell. Then the shell immediately stopped compiling and running python code and hanged up. See if someone can help to get the shell work well while Proxifier is on, or any other suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem. After trying a lot of things I arrived at this solution. The trick is to make a new Proxification Rule in proxifier. Name it anything you prefer, say PythonIdle.
  In application box add python.exe and pythonw.exe.
  Set action to Direct.

Hope it will solves your problem!

Comment: What if I want to use a proxy with python IDLE instead of using "Direct" connection?